# On hover event of one div display another div as well as another div should remain display on its hover also

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to make my another div remain display - in this plunker it's text "hello" on it's hover event. My another div is not child element of my main div on which I call my hover event.

```js
document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false">
        Mouse over me.
      </span>
  <br /><br />
  <div ng-show="show">Hello!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Link to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ro80nR7HT7OGGPCXjz7E?p=preview).

Comment: Change the question more understandably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <span ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false">
        Mouse over me.
      </span>
      <div ng-show="show" ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false">Hello!</div>
```